# Access the scope in a class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model `User`, which has a relationship `tags`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base #id, name, email, ...
  has_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base #id, name, ...
  def self.add_tag(tag)
    self.create!({user_id:user.id, tag: tag})
  end
end

User.tags.add_tag("abc")
```

How does the class method `add_tag` know the relationship that is referenced?

Comment: Here `self.create!({user_id:user.id, tag: tag})`, `user` is undefined

Comment: This `User.tags.add_tag("abc")` will cause _undefined method tags for User class_ error

Comment: Instead of complicating the logic so much, you can simply do `user.tags.create!(tag: 'abc')`. You don't need a separate method unless you are doing extensive calculations/assignments in that.

Answer (score -2):

I Apparently, calling create in the class method will set the scope appropriately

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base #id, name, email, ...
  has_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base #id, name, ...
  def self.add_tag(tag)
    self.create!({ tag: tag})
  end
end

user.tags.add_tag("abc")
```

This'll work just fine

Comment: This `User.tags.add_tag("abc")` will cause _undefined method tags for User class_ error